# How can I use Spyder with multiple virtual environments?

Tags: python, virtualenv, spyder

To use Spyder with multiple virtual environments you need a spyder.ini file for each virtual environment. Is there a command line option to set the spyder.ini to use when launching spyder ? Something like:

```
spyder -ini <my ini file here>
```

I can't find how to do that so I use the following script to accomplish that:

```
echo "Starting spyder..."
cp ~/.config/spyder-py3/spyder.ini temp.spyder.ini
cp my_ini_file_here ~/.config/spyder-py3/spyder.ini
/usr/bin/spyder3 --new-instance -p "my project path here"
echo "Restoring spyder.ini..."
cp ~/.config/spyder-py3/spyder.ini "my ini file here"
cp temp.spyder.ini ~/.config/spyder-py3/spyder.ini
rm temp.spyder.ini
```

The -p argument is optional.

Comment: I think for the moment there is not a full solution for that kind of workflow in Spyder. However, there is an [issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/ux-improvements/issues/10) where the UI/UX for changing interpreters is being discussed and also there is some documentation about the current functionality regarding how to change the [interpreter](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html?highlight=interpreter#using-existing-environment)

Comment: @DanielAlthviz It would be as easy as allowing me to set the spyder.ini file when launching spyder. That would be better than having to change the interpreter manually every time I open spyder for a different environment. And of course much better than installing spyder multiple times.